# Using get-Property method to read http post parameters

Tags: xml, http-post, wso2, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

First let me explain what I am trying then I shall get to the problem I am facing...
I am using wso2 esb to create a proxy web service such that I can send http post request to an exisiting web serive. Consider SimpleStockQuote web service hosted in the sample axis2 server. Now I want to proxy it and send the symbol via http post request. Can someone explain how it can be done?

Currently simplestockquote service accepts and replies in soap message format only. I am thinking about using some xslt transformation.  Any link to a working sample woud be a lot of help.

Thanks in advance.!!

This can serve as an example of what I actually want...

Right now I can send post request to my proxy or the service directly of the form :

curl "http://localhost:8280/services/StockQuoteProxy" -X POST -d 'IBM' -v -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -H "SOAPACtion: urn:getQuote"

And it works now I want my request to be of the form :

curl "http://localhost:8280/services/StockQuoteProxy" -X POST -d 'function=getQuote&synbol=IBM' -v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll find the following examples useful.

- [Sample 152](http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/4.0.3/docs/samples/proxy_samples.html#Sample152): Switching transports and message format from SOAP to REST/POX
- [Sample 440](http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/4.0.3/docs/samples/advanced_mediation_samples.html#Sample440): Exposing a SOAP Service Over JSON

Comment: I have edited the question a bit to explain my query more neatly..please do have a look...